# How to detect if mouse is outside of the document when mouseup fires?

Tags: javascript, dom

Let's say I `mousedown` a blank area in the page with right-button, then move the cursor out of the document while still pressing the button, then I finally release it. I want to prevent `mouseup` action because it fired outside of the document.

I could compare the coordinates of the event with the limits of the window, but there's a possibility that the user has an application pinned ("always on top") over part of the browser window, so releasing the button over it is also outside, but coordinates wouldn't tell.

I thought I could solve it with this:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
 if (!document.documentElement.matches(':hover')) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
 }
}, false);
```

But `document.documentElement.matches(':hover')` is still true! I didn't know `:hover` state change waits for the click to end, this doesn't sound right to me.

I can use `setTimeout` to delay `document.documentElement.matches(':hover')`, but I wonder if there is a more suitable way, because a short delay can fail if the browser is busy, while a longer one may not provide the best UX.

I have also tried `mouseover`, `mouseout` and the like, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try using, you might have to edit it and stuff but might work

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
 document.querySelector('*:hover').forEach((el) => {
  if(el === document) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //rest of the stuff you want to do...
   } else {
    //other the stuff you want to do if mouse in document...
   }
 });
}, false);
```